# Rails server not responding on get request have to kill process to end server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason when I call debt.user.payments.... on my debt.rb model file (it's in a each loop with |debt|) my server will just freeze/not respond and the only way for me to actually quit the server is to ctrl-z then kill the process.

Any idea why this isn't working? I can include more of the method this code is surrounded in if needed.

here is the code:

```
if debt.user.payments.map(&:expected_on).include?(date)
      debt.balance = adj_bal - (calculating_debt_payment(debts) + debt.minimum_payment + debt.user.payments.where(:expected_on => date))
    end
```

and the last thing the server logs show:

```
Started GET "/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-12 17:16:50 +1100


ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (20.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (15.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Debt Load (29.9ms)  SELECT "debts".* FROM "debts"  WHERE "debts"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "debts".* FROM "debts"  WHERE "debts"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "debts".* FROM "debts"  WHERE "debts"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Payment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments"  WHERE "payments"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
^C^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 rails s
```

Comment: I am not sure, but try something like this `debt.includes(:user).payments.pluck(:expected_on)`

Comment: Nah still getting the error! Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: this you are doing in model?

Comment: yes in my debt.rb model file

Comment: so what is that debt, it should be `Debt` or `self`

Comment: nah its supposed to be `debt` becuase its in a block i.e. `debts.reduce(0) do |acc, debt|`

Comment: try doing it for one Debt then if it is working you can loop for all

Comment: i tried your first method again and am actually getting `'undefined method 'includes' for <Debt.....'`

Comment: it's called eager loading, you should be able to use that